# Xamarin WatchOS app Storyboards are not opening/working in Xcode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

So VS for Mac 2022 dropped the storyboard support and Microsoft suggest to Xcode to change storyboards but When I right click on Storyboard in VS4Mac and select open with "Xcode Interface Builder" an error occurs telling me that "Error updating Objective-C type information".
I thought that this might be general issue but indeed only for WatchOs project specific, when i try the same thing using a normal Ios Phone project, it just works fine and opens it in Xcode.
I am guessing that this problem occurs in WatchOs project because Storyboard and Controller are in the 2 separate projects. 1 is WatchOSApp other in the Extension project.
So what is the workaround with this?
I tried to open directly from the finder and it opens fine in Xcode but when I make changes, it doesn't update InterfaceController.designer.cs at all.
How to fix this or is it a bug?

PS; in General Apple looks like dropped the storyboard and objective-c support and pushing towards SwiftUI. Does that even mean that in the future it makes no sense to use Xamarin.Ios native for watchOs?

Comment: I don’t think Xamarin supports WatchOS any longer, although the docs don’t explicitly say that.  I’ve seen a thread in GitHub that discusses this

Comment: @Jason in which github discussion ? can you please post the link? If you mean Maui discussion, I have seen that too but this is for maui that wont support. I didnt see anything about Xamarin Native. my understanding is that Xamarin.forms support will drop in 2024 but Xamarin.native for ios and android should be still there and watchos is also native.